# Missing parameters in GRPC API response

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers, grpc

I have setup a GRPC API using C++. One of the parameters is missing from the response. I am able to fix it by explicitly making it optional. But I would like to understand it.

The proto file look as follows (updated after suggestions in comments). I do not get `status` in the `APIResponse`. All other parameters are received.

```
syntax = "proto3";

package test_api;

enum Status {
    UNKNOWN = 0;
    COMPLETED = 1;
    IN_PROGRESS = 2;
    ERROR = 3;
}

message APIResponse {
    int32 id = 1;
    Status status = 2;
    string val = 3;
}
```

However, if I add the `optional` flag to the `status`, it works as expected.

```
message APIResponse {
    int32 id = 1;
    optional Status status = 2;
    string val = 3;
}
```

As per the proto3 syntax, the parameters `optional` and `required` are obsolete now.
[Github Protobuf Issue](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/issues/2497#issuecomment-267422550)

I test the API using postman.

Could I be doing anything wrong?

Comment: Have you checked the version for your protoc compiler? Also note that it is best to move the Status enum into the response and reserve Status value 0 for unknown errors (grpc maps unknown values not part of the enum to 0, which might happen when you have multiple versions)

Comment: @PepijnKramer I am using protobuf 21.6 and grpc 1.52.0

Thanks for alerting me about the value 0. I was not careful about it. But the problem remains despite correcting it.

Comment: I know value 0 would not solve the problem but it might be later

Comment: Is your server actually populating the status field? How did you determine that you "did not get `status`". If your server is not populating the field and the way you are determining that `status` is not present is simply by the field not being listed in the JSON debug string, this is working as intended. In proto3, for non-optional fields, there is no way to distinguish between default values (UNKNOWN in this case) and unset fields. So fields with default values are left unprinted in debug output.